# Adding more than 1 bars to a splittercontainer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

Is it possible to add more than 1 spliter to a splittercontainerboth in Devexpress or Winforms control?I tried nesting containers in containers,but the main container blocks the movement of the child splitter bar,so is it possible to create a flexible splitter container in that way? :)

Answer (score 0):

SplitPanels can be nested but can only contain 2 panels per control, so nesting is necessary to get more than those 2 panels or more bars. Could you elaborate on *the main container blocks the movement of the child splitter bar*?

Comment: Well,since the child containers are nested inside the main container,the main container's split bar controls the movement of the child containers,for example i cannot slide the splitter bar of the child container to the end of the page,it just moves where the parents splitter bar is,and stops there,but if i move the parent container's ,the it allows the child splitter bar to move..They are not independent to be precise...

Comment: One solution can be to dock the child containers to the panels of the parent (dock > fill). That way the child control's dimensions can't exceed the parent's panel sizes.